# Comparing and synchronizing data across oracle instances

Tags: oracle, compare

I have three oracle environments.  If I make changes to the data in my DEV environment, I want to be able to take those changes and move them to my other environments.

The challenge is that the data in the other environments will not have the same primary key. So the compare would have to look at the other columns in the table. If the table referenced another table, it would have to include columns from that table as well.

So, for example, table A might have 4 columns that were all IDs to other tables, and so manipulating table A would require referring to those other tables. Can anyone suggest a product for this?

Updated Requirements: Nothing about the systems as they currently stand can be changed.  IDs will never be in synch.  The synchronization must only happen when desired (after our bi-monthly updates).  Synchronization can not be done over DB links (though the DEV system can read data across the DB links).  I can definitely write the SQL to do all this, its just the kind of thing that is prone to error (and typos) and if there is a 3rd party application out there that can take care of this for me, I'd rather spend the money on that.

Updates as per request: All systems are 11g Enterprise.  The amount of data is very small, bandwidth isn't an issue.  The synchronization happens every couple of months.  Basically, we have rules that tell our UI how to behave.  Those rules are stored in various tables.  From time to time, we change those rules.  This can be thousands of records, but not tens of thousands.  We don't want the kind of synchronization that one might want from 'live' data.  What I need to be able to do is specify the two database instances, and the tables in question, and then have a SQL script generated that, effectively, moves the changes from database A to database B.  Given the nature of the data, I've been considering simply truncating the target tables and sqlloading the data into the other environments.  That isn't quite as simple as it sounds as there is one 'live' table that refers to these records and that would require some specific updates potentially (I'm actively researching this possibility as well, it just isn't as simple as it sounds).

Here's code that will provide examples of what I mean.  You'll notice IDs, and those are NOT consistent across environments, which is what makes this tricky.

```
drop table mydata;
drop table MYTOWN;
drop table MYJOB;
drop table MYEMPLOYER;
drop table mystate;

create table MYJOB
(MYJOBID varchar2(1000)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MYJOB varchar2(1000));

create table MYEMPLOYER
(MYEMPLOYERID  varchar2(1000)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MYEMPLOYER  varchar2(1000));


create table MYSTATE
(MYSTATEID  varchar2(1000)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MYSTATE varchar2(1000));

create table MYTOWN
(MYTOWNID varchar2(1000)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MYTOWN varchar2(1000),
MYSTATEID varchar2(1000),
CONSTRAINT MYSTATE_FK FOREIGN KEY (MYSTATEID) REFERENCES MYSTATE (MYSTATEID) ENABLE);


create table MYDATA
(MYDATAID varchar2(1000)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MYTOWNID varchar2(1000),
MYJOBID varchar2(1000),
MYEMPLOYERID varchar2(1000),
CONSTRAINT MYTOWN_FK FOREIGN KEY (MYTOWNID) REFERENCES MYTOWN (MYTOWNID) ENABLE,
CONSTRAINT MYJOB_FK FOREIGN KEY (MYJOBID) REFERENCES MYJOB (MYJOBID) ENABLE,
CONSTRAINT MYEMPLOYER_FK FOREIGN KEY (MYEMPLOYERID) REFERENCES MYEMPLOYER (MYEMPLOYERID) ENABLE
);


create sequence mydataid_seq;

insert into myemployer values ('937436',    'Bank Of America');
insert into myemployer values  ('43',   'Google');
insert into myemployer values  ('2',    'Toms Taxi');

insert into myjob  values ('8','Programmer');
insert into myjob  values ('10','Cook');
insert into myjob  values ('5','Driver');

insert into mystate  values ('7643','MA');
insert into mystate  values ('23','CA');
insert into mystate  values ('54','NM');

insert into mytown  values ('4743','BOSTON','7643');
insert into mytown  values ('321','SANDIEGO','23');
insert into mytown  values ('92037','SANTA FE','54');

insert into mydata  values ('78','4743','8','937436');
insert into mydata  values ('23455','321','10','43');
insert into mydata  values ('901','92037','5','2');


--to select a unique row
select mt.mytown, ms.mystate, mj.myjob, me.myemployer
from mydata md, mytown mt, mystate ms, myemployer me, myjob mj
where md.mytownid=mt.mytownid
and mt.mystateid=ms.mystateid
and md.myjobid=mj.myjobid
and md.myemployerid=me.myemployerid;

--to delete a row
delete from mydata md where md.mydataid =
(select md.mydataid 
from mydata md, mytown mt, mystate ms, myemployer me, myjob mj
where md.mytownid=mt.mytownid
and mt.mystateid=ms.mystateid
and md.myjobid=mj.myjobid
and md.myemployerid=me.myemployerid
and mt.mytown='SANDIEGO'
and ms.mystate='CA'
and mj.myjob='Cook'
and me.myemployer='Google');

--to insert a row
insert into mydata (mydataid,mytownid, myjobid, myemployerid)
(select mydataid_seq.nextval, mt.mytownid, mj.myjobid, me.myemployerid
from mytown mt, mystate ms, myemployer me, myjob mj
where mt.mytown='SANTA FE'
and mj.myjob='Programmer'
and me.myemployer='Toms Taxi'
and ms.mystate='NM'
);
```

Comment: What version(9i, 10g, 11g) and edition (Standard, Enterprise etc.) of the Oracle Database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Oracle GoldenGate.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html
May be it would be like a heavy gun solution.

The best solution depends on your concrete needs (how much data? how often? how much transformation must done? bandwidth between servers? their load? and so on...).

Oracle has many replication options.

**Update:**

Advise about GoldenGate is still actual, but it isn't cheap solution.

But, if you have some coding skills and interest, then it maybe easier to:

1. use db-link and write PLSQL packages with a syncing logic. Then, you can call it when you need, or run it regularly as Job/Task. Central database must see others and must have an ability to establish a direct connection.
2. or you can write an external application and place a syncing logic there. Databases could be in separate DMZs.

Of course, you can use Oracle Streams (11g enterprise includes it), but i can't guarantee that it would work without additional codding in your case. So, this approach can turn into first one with complications.

Sometimes, using serious replication solutions take more time for setting up them and maintain. In your case, you need just a syncing.

And you can find some kind of ready and free solutions. But, in most cases they suffer from poor quality. So, I don't recommend them.

PS: 
You can solve inconsistence of data, by using two approaches:

1. Easiest: use oracle sequences with different start values for key columns for each database (don't forget to set up max value too, to prevent overlapping)
2. Normal solution: redesign your data model to include information about office/server

Comment: I really don't have the option of changing sequences on the other systems.  This is the situation that I have to work within.  The only way I've figured out how to do this in my current situation is to compare the tables across DB links and then generate sql based on those results so that I can then run that SQL in all instances.  Again, this is just how it is.
I was hoping to find a 3rd party application that would do this as writing this code is, while not difficult, fairly labor intensive and theres a LOT of room for typos.

Comment: btw, that totally came across much more sharply than I'd intended.  My apologies.